# Do something after returning a response?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, response

Im looking for a way to do the following:

```
return res.send(response).then({
    someFunc()
  })
```

*After the `send()` occurs the `then()` block runs allowing me to call some function in the backend.*

**Is there a way to do this?**

What I currently have above yields an error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token } eslint

Comment: You're wrapping the function inside a curly brace. it should be `res.send(response).then(someFunc);`

Comment: @ryeballar this worked! Add as answer

Comment: It's fine, you can accept the answer below, it shares the same format.

Comment: I had problems using the accepted solution. This solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350437/typeerror-res-send-then-is-not-a-function/67351476#67351476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see eslint can't parse your code.
Inside the `then` method is a function but you're sending an object with the curly braces.

```
return res.send(response).then((result) => {
  someFunc();
});
```