# TypeError: res.send(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Inside of my `index.js` I have a function which ends like this:

```js
return res.send(response).then(saveProductID(uid, product.id));
```

In the Firebase console its says:

> TypeError: res.send(...).then is not a function

Full code example:

```js
exports.createConnectAccount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var data = req.body
    console.log(data, "<--  clark jable")
    var uid = data.userID
    console.log(uid, "<--  this is the uid")
    var email = data.email
    var response = {}
    strip.accounts.create({
            type: 'express',
            country: 'US',
            requested_capabilities: [
                'transfers',
            ],
            business_type: 'individual',
        },
        (err, account) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Couldn't create stripe account: " + err)

                return res.send(err)
            }
            // createStripe_customers(uid, customer, intent)
            console.log("ACCOUNT: " + account.id)
            response.body = {
                success: account.id
            }
            //createStripe_customers()
            return res.send(response).then(createStripe_Accounts(uid, account));
        }
    );
});

function createStripe_Accounts(uid, account) {
    console.log(uid, " did the createStripe_Accounts Run? ", account.id)
    const userRef = admin.database().ref('Stripe_Accounts').child(uid) //.child(uid)
    return userRef.set({
        account_id: account.id,
    });
}
```

`.then()` has worked before (and continues to) for many other functions. **So why is this error popping up for the `createConnectAccount` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing in the documentation or [source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) that implies Response.send will return a Promise, nor do I see any code examples that assume it does. It is not an async function, and it seems it will return `this` in the common success case (and even this is not documented).

I wonder if you have been "getting lucky" with this in the past because you have been using `.then()` not on the specific return value of `res.send` but instead on the return value of an async function that returns it:

```
async foo(res) {
  return res.send();
}

foo().then(a => console.log('this will work.'));
```

Because the JS runtime will automatically wrap the return value of an `async` function in a Promise, you'll always get a thenable object when using this pattern.

I'm not sure about the specifics in your code snippet, but I believe the following will have the behavior you seem to be after:

```
res.send(response)
return createStripe_Accounts(uid, account);
```